# How to size logo image in disappear on scroll navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I did not use bootstrap because I couldn't get it to function.

I've used HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I want to have the logo image be the same size as the nav bar and disappear on scroll. Also, if anyone has suggestions on how to shift the home/ contact/ etc to the right, away from the logo image, that would be great.

Here's the code:

```js
/* When the user scrolls down, hide the navbar. When the user scrolls up, show the navbar */
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

```css
  #navbar {
    background-color: #333; /* Black background color */ 
    position: fixed; /* Make it stick/fixed */
    top: 0; /* Stay on top */
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    transition: top 0.3s; /* Transition effect when sliding down (and up) */
  } 
  
  /* Style the navbar links */
  #navbar a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  #navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
  }
 
  .logo-image img{
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -6px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
        
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="images/Besosnbuds.jpg">
            <div class="logo-image">
                  <img src="images/Besosnbuds.jpg" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
      

        <a href="index.html">Home </a>
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <a class="social_media" href="https://www.facebook.com/natalie.april.73"><i class="fa fa- fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a class="social_media" href="https://www.instagram.com/besosnbuds/"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To shift the Home, Contact, and About to the right away from the logo image, you should wrap the Home, Contact, and About anchor tags in a , and the same with the logo. then wrap those two divs in a containing `<div class='container'>`. Target container and add

```
.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
```

That should push the logo to the far left and everything else to the right.

As for getting the logo to disappear when you scroll, try adding

```
document.getElementById("logo-image").style.opacity = "0";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("logo-image").style.display = "none";
```

in the else statement.